# Searching folders and subfolders for a file and get its size depending on the name

Tags: c#, .net

I have a regular list of strings that contain filenames like

```
List<string> filenames = new List<string>{ "235253325_23522.jpg" };
```

What i want to do is iterate over the list and search through a folder and its subfolders and retrieve the file size of the current file name. I want to add upp all the `bytes` for all the hits from my list.

Just a note, if the filname exists in the list im 100% sure it exists in the main folder or one of the subfolders as well.

I know which folder to search through, im retrieving that through string

```
adPicturesPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AdPicturesPath"];
```

How would one approach to do this?

Comment: So you only have the filename and don't know the folder? What is the _main_-folder?

Comment: use class `Directory`to search all files in a directory and recursively all subdirectories.

Comment: I know which folder to search through, im retrieving that through 
string adPicturesPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AdPicturesPath"];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string adPicturesPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AdPicturesPath"];
List<string> files = new List<string> { "235253325_23522.jpg" };
var allFiles = files.SelectMany(fn => Directory.EnumerateFiles(adPicturesPath, fn, System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories));
long allFileSizeBytes = allFiles.Sum(fn => new FileInfo(fn).Length);
```

Comment: worked like a charm!. I was working with recursive methods trying to get it to work and had no success, this was super short and easy, thank you!